# Retrieving GameObject from new Enemy Encounters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How does one go about retrieving a game object from an enemy upon each new encounter? This isn't something I can plug into Unity's inspector. I don't have any code written for because I don't know where to begin. What I THINK I know so far:

I'm going to need a variable that can store a game object, but what happens when multiple enemies are encountered?

```
 GameObject getEnemy;
```

I'm probably going to have a collider set up to trigger when enemies are detected. Now I want to store the `GameObject`.

```
 getEnemy = getComponent<GameObject>();
```

But this doesn't work. Anyone know why?

************************* Actual Code (Doesn't Work) ***********************
(Class Name EnemyDetection)

```
  public static GameObject enemyObj;

  void OnTriggerEnter(){


   enemyObj = other.GetComponent<GameObject>(); //Grabs enemy object to pass 
                                                 to the enemies class

    }
```

(Class Name Enemies)

```
public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.tag == "Bullet")
    {
        GameObject en = EnemyDetection.enemyObj;

        Hp -= 25;

        Debug.Log("Hit! HP left " + Hp);
        if ( Hp <= 0)
        {
           Destroy(en); // Destroys GameObject
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `new encounter`? `GameObject` isn't a component you can get by `GetComponent`. All components have a reference to their `gameObject` though ...

Comment: The `GameObject` is an object that can hold multiple `Components` (i.e. Transform, Rigidbody, AudoSource, etc..) but is not a component itself. As far as the multiple enemies question, you can make a `List<GameObject>` and store them for reference, then use it upon request.

Comment: I have a collider set up that I call EnemyDetection. So whenever an enemy is nearby, this enemy detector needs to know what enemy the player is approaching. I'm trying to store the game object every single time there's an encounter because my enemy script doesn't actually carry the enemies game object/ therefore, I cannot destroy the enemy until I get the game object. And I'll need to do this each time a new enemy is detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.

As mentioned in comments `GameObjects` are things that contain different `Components` so you do `GetComponent<SomeComponent>` to get the components on a gameobject not the gameobject itself

As for your case.
Inside your trigger callback get the gameobject from the passed Collider object

```
//Or whatever callback you are using
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    //this "other" contains the gameobject as reference
    getEnemy = other.gameObject;

    //if now you need components from this then you do
    //example
    // other.gameObject.GetComponent<SomeComponent>();
}
```

Regarding the multiple enemies etc. you can just store then in a list or a dictionary.

### EDIT

```
//INCORRECT (There is no such thing as GetComponent<GameObject>())
enemyObj = other.GetComponent<GameObject>();

//CORRECT
enemyObj = other.gameObject;
```

And your OnTriggerEnter needs to have an Collider argument

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    enemyObj = other.gameObject;
}
```

Comment: Hey brother, very nice to see ya pop in! I updated my opening post with the code I'm trying to use now. As always, your opinions and advice is much appreciated!